# Why should I use Carp instead of warn in Perl?

Tags: perl, module, carp

People keep giving me examples with carp instead of warn.  Why?  What makes carp better than warn?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

carp gives you more info as to where the message comes from (context)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Carp;

foo();
bar();
baz();

sub foo {
  warn "foo";
}

sub bar {
  carp "bar";
}

sub baz {
  foo();
  bar(); 
}
```

produces

```
foo at ./foo.pl line 9.
bar at ./foo.pl line 13
        main::bar() called at ./foo.pl line 6
foo at ./foo.pl line 10.
bar at ./foo.pl line 14
        main::bar() called at ./foo.pl line 19
        main::baz() called at ./foo.pl line 7
```

kinda silly for this small program but comes in handy when you want to know who called the method that's carp'ing.

Answer (score 23):

I use `warn` for scripts and simple programs, and `Carp` inside any modules. The `Carp` subroutines use the filename and line number where your current subroutine was called so it's easier to find who's causing the problem (not just where the problem manifested itself).

Damian recommends `Carp` instead of `warn` in "Reporting Failure" in *Perl Best Practices*, but doesn't make the distinction between scripts as top-level code constructs and modules as components that programs use.

I've mostly not cared about that lately because I've been using [Log::Log4perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Log-Log4perl) to handle all of that.

Answer (score 12):

carp works better for debugging within modules.  If you are only writing a simple script, there is no benefit.  From [the Carp documenation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Carp.html):

> The Carp routines are useful in your own modules because they act like die() or warn(), but with a message which is more likely to be useful to a user of your module. In the case of cluck, confess, and longmess that context is a summary of every call in the call-stack. For a shorter message you can use carp or croak  which report the error as being from where your module was called. There is no guarantee that that is where the error was, but it is a good educated guess.

Answer (score 8):

`Carp` reports errors from the caller's perspective. This is useful for modules where you typically want to warn about incorrect usage (e.g. a missing argument) and identify the place where the error *occurred* as opposed to where it was *detected.* This is especially important for utility functions that might be used in many places.

Most authors use `warn` in scripts and `carp` in modules. Occasionally I use `warn` inside a module when I want the error message to reflect a problem in the module's implementation (e.g. a case that it should support but doesn't.) It's arguable that `cluck` would be better in such situations as it provides a full stack backtrace.