# Can't disable stack trace in Carp::croak() for some reason

Tags: perl

According to the Carp module documentation, `croak()` should not produce any stack trace unless `$Carp::Verbose` evaluates to true. But for some reasone, `croak()` always behaves like `confess()` in my environment, i.e. always printing a stack trace, even when it should not..

Here is a test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl;
use Carp;

sub func
{
    say "Carp::Verbose = $Carp::Verbose";
    croak "There should be no stack trace after this message!";
}

sub main
{
    func();
}

main;
```

And here is the result it produces on my system:

```
$ ./croak
Carp::Verbose = 0
There should be no stack trace after this message! at ./croak line 8
    main::func() called at ./croak line 13
    main::main() called at ./croak line 16
```

Maybe someone has encountered this issue or has any clue about the root cause?

Here is some info about my environment:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Linux 3.2.0-27-generic x86_64
perl 5, version 14, subversion 2 (v5.14.2) built for x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
```

Also I get the same wrong behavior on my SL6 system:

```
Scientific Linux SL release 6.3 (Carbon)
kernel-2.6.32-279.1.1.el6.x86_64
perl, v5.10.1 (*) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of `Carp`'s rules for which frame of the stack trace to use for the error message is:

> 1. Any call from a package to itself is safe.

Since your code doesn't use any packages other than `main`, and since another rule is that the `Carp` package itself is safe, `Carp` can't decide what line of code to use for its error message, so it punts and prints out the whole stack trace.

Oh, it's actually there in the `Carp` perldoc:

> What they do is search the call-stack for a function call stack where thay have not been told that there shouldn't be an error. **If every call is marked safe, they give up and give a full stack backtrace instead.**

This line in the `Carp::short_error_loc` function is your smoking gun:

```
return 0 unless defined($caller);    # What happened?
```

Comment: I've found the following answer to question about [Carp vs warn/die](http://stackoverflow.com/a/188846/1559353), indeed Damian Conway recommends to use `carp` over `warn` in his PBP book. So I'm wondering is this a good practice to use `warn/die` in `main` package (i.e. in script) and use `carp/croak` only in modules?

Comment: @DimaChumak: yes, you should use `warn / die` in scripts, and `carp/croak` in modules.

Answer (score 3):

Half an answer: it has something to do with the code being all in the same package. If you call the entry point from a different package, `croak` works as you expect.