# How can I mark a call as "unsafe" with Carp?

Tags: perl, carp

I have the same problem as in [Can't disable stack trace in Carp::croak() for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879457/cant-disable-stack-trace-in-carpcroak-for-some-reason).  Because every call in the stack is considered "safe", `croak()` prints out a full stack trace every time.  I'd like to disable that for certain calls.

Here's an example:

```
use Carp;

sub this_may_fail {
  # Some code...
  croak "This call failed!";
}

sub regular_code {
  this_may_fail();
}

regular_code();
```

Both subroutines are in the same package, so `this_may_fail` is automatically marked as safe.  Is there any way to tell Carp that `this_may_fail` should be considered unsafe?

Comment: Is `regular_code()` the only thing calling `this_may_fail`? If so then you could just use a regular `die`

Comment: `this_may_fail` gets called from several different locations, and I need to know where it was called from so I can figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `regular_code` that's considered "safe" by `this_may_fail`. The check is based on namespace, so to make it unsafe, you'd place `this_may_fail` in a different namespace.

---

Or write your own croaker.

```
perl -e'
   use Carp qw( );
   sub untrusting_croak {
      goto &Carp::croak if $Carp::Verbose;
      my @caller = caller(1);
      die(join("", @_)." at $caller[1] line $caller[2]\n");
   }

   sub f { untrusting_croak("!!!"); }    # Line 9

   f();                                  # Line 11
'
!!! at -e line 11
```

Comment: I ended up moving some of my functions to a different namespace.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Not especialy pretty, but, instead of this:

```
sub regular_code {
   ...;
   my $result = this_may_fail(@args);
}
```

You could use this...

```
sub regular_code {
   ...;
   my $result = do {
      my $sub = \&this_may_fail;
      package DUMMY; $sub->(@args)
   };
}
```